# How compile C++ program with PDCurses?

Tags: c++, pdcurses

I try compile Windows program which uses PDCurses. While this code is in plain C, it is OK, but if I change to C++, is error:

```
'_bool': must be a simple type or resolve to one
in h:\programfiles\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.10.25017\include\vadefs.h    127
```

If I define _CRT_NO_VA_START_VALIDATION is better, but still errors: 
in "typedef bool  __vcrt_bool" and "typedef unsigned char bool" in headers.
All these errors are connected with "bool".

Comment: These problems are with library from http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/pdcurses.htm, but is https://sourceforge.net/projects/pdcurses/ that is solution.

Comment: Did you include a C header, such as `<stdbool.h>`?